# My PostUpdateView does not send any data to form update template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-generic-views

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGEt7.png)
I have exactly the same structure for updating forum's posts, so they do work, but the article's ones don't. My article_update_form template simple does not receive any data from the view and therefore the slug is empty.

model

```
class ArticlePost(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=400)
slug = models.CharField(max_length=400, unique=True, blank=True)
article_users = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="article_users")
content = models.TextField()
categories = models.ManyToManyField(ArticleCategory)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
hit_count_generic = GenericRelation(HitCount, object_id_field="object_pk",
                                        related_query_name="hit_count_generic_relation")
article_tags = TaggableManager(related_name="article_tags")
article_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="article_images/")

def __str__(self) -> str:
    return self.title

@property
def length(self) -> int:
    return len(self.content)

@property
def get_category(self):
    return [v for v in self.categories.all()]

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    super(ArticlePost, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("article_details", kwargs={
        "slug": self.slug
})
```

My UpdateView

```
class ArticlePostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = ArticlePost
    template_name = 'articles/article_form_update.html'
    form_class = ArticlePostForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        messages.success(self.request, 'The article has been updated')
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user.id == post.article_users.user.id:
            return True
        return False
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("posts/<slug>/", articles, name="articles"),
    path('<int:page_id>', pages.views.articles, name='page'),
    path("detail/<slug>/", detail, name="article_details"),
    path("new_article", new_article, name="new_article"),
    path("new_article/create_post", login_required(ArticlePostCreateView.as_view()), name="create_article"),
    path("post/<slug:slug>/update/", ArticlePostUpdateView.as_view(), name="update_post_article"),
    path('categories_list', categories_list, name="categories_list"),
    path("search_article_post", search_article_post, name="search_article_post"),
    path("category/<slug>/", category_articles, name="category_articles"),
    path("sort_by/<str:typesort>", articles_sort, name="articles_sort"),
]
```

forms:

```
class ArticlePostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ArticlePost
        fields = ("title", "categories", "content", "article_tags", 'article_image')
        exclude = ["article_users"]

        widget = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'content': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'categories': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'article_tags': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'article_image': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
    
    def __setitem__(self, i, elem):
        self.list[i] = elem
```

form template:

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <form method="POST" action="{% url 'update_post_article' slug=post.slug %}">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <div class="centered_create_post">
                                    {% render_field form.title placeholder="Enter title" class+="form-control each_post_create" %}
                                    {% render_field form.content  placeholder="Enter content" class+="form-control each_post_create pst_create_categories " %}
                                    {% render_field form.categories  class+="form-control each_post_create pst_create_categories " %}
                                    {% render_field form.article_image  class+="form-control each_post_create" %}
                                        <div class="pull-left"><button type="submit" class="btn_create_post">Update Post</button></div>
                                </div>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

When I tried to use get_context_data, I could send the post manually to the form template but the form does not render any of the widgets from the forms.py.

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'update_post_article' slug=post.slug %}">
```

To:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'update_post_article' post.slug %}">
```

Comment: I tried this way too, but it still doesnt work. (the same error)

Comment: can you then try the code without passing anything in the action attribute? Do you get any errors?
`<form method="POST" action="">`

Comment: Also post your model.py

Comment: no I dont. When I enter whatever data (slug, id etc) to action, it becomes empty. Posted model